# How to handle multiple requests and guaranteed save to the postgres database using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, database, prisma

I am writing my backend using node.js and TypeScript. The server is quite simple, it basically just handles REST requests from the frontend and also has direct access to the postgres via prisma ORM (https://www.prisma.io/). So consider this simple case:

1. Frontend sends request to the endpoint '/dashboard/setContribution' with body that includes that contribution
2. This will be routed (in my backend) to this function:

```
const MAX_RETRIES = 3;
const INITIAL_WAIT_TIME = 500;  // 500 ms

const retryOperation = async (operation: any, maxRetries: number, waitTime: number): Promise<any> => {
  try {
    return await operation();
  } catch (error) {
    if (maxRetries <= 0) throw error;
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, waitTime));
    return retryOperation(operation, maxRetries - 1, waitTime * 2);
  }
}


public setNewContribution = async (req: any, res: any) => {
    try {
      // fetch user and pool from db
      const token = getTokenFromHeader(req);
      const user = await retryOperation(() => this.dbOps.getUserByToken(token), MAX_RETRIES, INITIAL_WAIT_TIME) as User;
      const pool = await retryOperation(() => this.dbOps.getPoolInfo(), MAX_RETRIES, INITIAL_WAIT_TIME) as Pool;

      if (!user || !pool || !req.contribution) {
        return;
      }

      // Store the previous available amount
      user.prevAvailableAmount = user.currentAvailableAmount;

      // Add new contribution
      user.totalContributed += req.body.contribution;
      user.LastContributedDate = new Date();

      // Calculate the proportion of the user's contribution to the total pool contribution
      let contributionProportion =
        BigInt(user.totalContributed!) / pool.totalContributions!;

      // Determine the current available amount for the user based on the proportion
      let currentAvailableAmount =
        Number(contributionProportion * (pool.totalContributions! - pool.totalClaims!));

      // Calculate the change in all available amounts
      let allAvailableAmountsChange = currentAvailableAmount - user.prevAvailableAmount!;

      // Adjust the claims
      let adjustedClaims = Math.min(
        user.totalContributed! * 2,
        user.totalClaimed!
      );
      let availableAmount;

      if (adjustedClaims < user.totalContributed!) {
        availableAmount = currentAvailableAmount! - adjustedClaims;
      } else {
        availableAmount = 0;
      }

      pool.totalAvailableSums! += BigInt(allAvailableAmountsChange);
      user.currentAvailableAmount = availableAmount;

      await this.dbOps.setUpdatedUserAndPoolAtClaim(user, pool);

    } catch (error) {
      logger.error(`dashboard.controller.ts::setNewContribution: Exception happened: ${error}`);
      return res.status(500).send('Server experienced an exception');
    }
  };
```

This function just tries at least 3 times to get the latest `user`and `pool` from the database and then does some local calculations and updates the database by providing new `user` and `pool` values.

3. The actual database operation using prisma looks like this (yes, I decided to use transactions to make sure that I update both `user` and `pool` otherwise throw an error)

```
public setUpdatedUserAndPoolAtClaim = async (updatedUser: User, updatedPool: Pool) => {
    const updateUserOperation = this.prisma.user.update({
      where: {
        personalNumber: updatedUser.personalNumber
      }, 
      data: {
        prevAvailableAmount: updatedUser.prevAvailableAmount,
        currentAvailableAmount: updatedUser.currentAvailableAmount,
        totalContributed: updatedUser.totalContributed,
        LastContributedDate: updatedUser.LastContributedDate
      }
    });

    const updatePoolOperation = this.prisma.pool.update({
      where: {
        singleton: true
      }, 
      data: {
        totalContributions: updatedPool.totalContributions,
        totalAvailableSums: updatedPool.totalAvailableSums
      }
    })

    const [userUpdated, poolUpdated] = await this.prisma.$transaction([
      updateUserOperation,
      updatePoolOperation
    ]);
```

So my questions are:

1. What would be the best practice to handle race conditions and ensure that backend would handle multiple requests to this endpoint? I thought to use some kind of versioning in the table so that before updating the `pool` I would read again its version and if not the same retry?
2. Even though I would check before updating, how to handle retries correctly? As returning 500 back to the frotnend is catastrophic as user would be just without this contribution saved in the database...

As this is not really a bug but design question, the current implementation works as it is but I would like to get opinion from experts.